# MediaStreamSource.SampleRequested event is not called (in UWP) when video encoding is created with specific height/width

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using MediaStreamSource to wrap a given video frame encoded in I420 format (code below). Whenever I get a frame width/height of a specific value (ie:- say height-1037 and width-1932), media foundation playback pipeline is not invoking the "SampleRequested" event to start playing the video frames. But when the frames received are close to height-600 and width 1080 for instance, it is getting triggered. I'm not sure what could be preventing the media foundation pipeline to not trigger "SampleRequested" event. From logs, I could see

> No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D5212).

But not sure how to rectify. Any pointers?

```
        private MediaStreamSource CreateI420VideoStreamSource(uint width, uint height,int framerate)
    {
        if (width == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid zero width for video.", "width");
        }
        if (height == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid zero height for video.", "height");
        }
        // Note: IYUV and I420 have same memory layout (though different FOURCC)
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/video-subtype-guids
        var videoProperties = VideoEncodingProperties.CreateUncompressed(MediaEncodingSubtypes.Iyuv,
                                                                        width, height);            
        var videoStreamDesc = new Windows.Media.Core.VideoStreamDescriptor(videoProperties);
        videoStreamDesc.EncodingProperties.FrameRate.Numerator = (uint)framerate;
        videoStreamDesc.EncodingProperties.FrameRate.Denominator = 1;
        videoStreamDesc.EncodingProperties.Height = height;
        videoStreamDesc.EncodingProperties.Width = width;
        // Bitrate in bits per second : framerate * frame pixel size * I420=12bpp
        //videoStreamDesc.EncodingProperties.Bitrate = ((uint)framerate * width * height * 12);
        var videoStreamSource = new Windows.Media.Core.MediaStreamSource(videoStreamDesc);
        videoStreamSource.BufferTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,0);
        videoStreamSource.SampleRequested += OnMediaStreamSourceRequested;
        videoStreamSource.IsLive = true; // Enables optimizations for live sources
        videoStreamSource.CanSeek = false; // Cannot seek live WebRTC video stream
        return videoStreamSource;
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to test this behavior with other formats and will this happen as well?

Comment: Tested with Argb32, it works well over there. Seeing this issue only when the format is IYUV.

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe the issue is related to the width/height value which is not the standard size. I'll ask other guys to check this as well.

Comment: Yeah may be… but other format seems to accept and render well for the same height/width. Looks like an issue specific to iyuv. Yes pls let me know if you get an leads. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I got some more information about your issue. First of all, the error message is correct, the codec (IYUV here) does not support the Height/Width that you are trying to use. You could refer to this document to enumerate the codec and find all the supported values: [Encoding video and audio with Media Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-concept).

Also, it is mentioned in the document that If you are creating custom presets, all values for height and width on AVC content must be a multiple of four.

Comment: Thank you Roy Li. This helps. In my case, I'm making a fallback to ARGB32 when the codec doesn't support.